# How to use post() jquery method with codeigniter form_validation

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to validate a form without refreshing the page using the `.post()` jQuery method.

I use codeigniter for validation. Could you please tell me how to make it right? I find it pretty confusing ...

Here is the jQuery code:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form_errors").hide();
  $("#send").on("click",function(){ //the submit button has the id="send"
    $(".form_errors").hide();  //these are <p> for each input to show the error
    var user=$("input.box");
    var data={};
    var names=$("input.box").attr("name");
    for(i=0;i<user.length;i++){
      name=names[i];
      value=user[i].val();
      data.name=value;
    }
    $.post('ksite/account',
           data,
           function(result){
             $("div.answer").html(result);
             for(i=0;i<user.length;i++){
               error_message=<?php echo form_error("?>names[i]<?php ");?>;
               $("p#error_"+names[i]+".form_errors").html(error_message).show();
             }
           }
           return false;});
  });
```

`form_error` is a CodeIgniter function. (I suppose someone who used ci is familiar with).

The form:

```html
<p id="error_user" class="form_errors"></p>
<input type="text" class="box" name="user">
<p id="error_password" class="form_errors"></p>
<input type="password" class="box" name="password">
<input type="submit" id="send">
```

Is the form tag neccessary ? And if yes,do i have to mention action and method ?
Do I have to specify the type of the response?

And in ksite/account I do:

```php
/* ...... */
if (!this->form_validation->run(''account")) {
  echo "The account couldn't be made";
} else {
  echo "The account was successfully created  ";
}
```

P.S.Although you may not be familiar with codeigniter, I would appreciate if someone could tell me if the code is correct and what improvements could be made.

Comment: There is a mistake in your PHP if condition `run(''account")` replace those two single-quotes with a double one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did.

You have to Ajax for getting data without refreshing the page.

HTML Page

```
$form = $(form);
var url = $form.attr('action');
dataString = $form.serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: dataString,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
$(data).each(function(j,details){
var status = details.status;
var message = details.message;
$('#message_ajax_register').show();
$('#message_ajax_register').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+message+'</div>');
});
}
});//end of $.ajax**
```

I am first setting up the rules in my controller method and then validating it.

Controller

```
    public function update_fest()
    {

        if($this->input->post())
        {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtgpluswebsite', 'Google Plus Page URL', 'trim|xss_clean|prep_url');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
            $message = validation_errors();
            $data = array('message' => $message,'status'=>0);
        } 
        else{
            $message = $this->add_fest_database();
            $data = $message;
        }
    }
    else{
            $message = "Fest details are required";
            $data = array('message' => $message,'status'=>0);   
        }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $json = $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
    return $json;
 }
```

If validation run is not false, then go to add_fest_database(other function). In that function,

```
    function add_fest_database()
    {
        $youtubeWebsite = $this->input->post('txtyoutubewebsite');
        $gplusWebsite = $this->input->post('txtgpluswebsite');
        $this->load->model('model_fest');
        $data = array("fest_youtube"=>$youtubeWebsite,"fest_gplus"=>$gplusWebsite);
        return  data;
     }
```

Comment: If the above answer is helpful, then mark it as useful so that other guys can use it. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use stackoverflow so often and i don't have enough reputation points to mark it as useful .